# VHDL-unconnected warning, 4 digit codelock

Tags: vhdl, fpga, xilinx, xilinx-ise

I am working on a project and I'm failing to to figure it out. I just can't see what I'm doing wrong. Any suggestions are highly appreciated. This project is in VHDL and this is about 4 digit combination lock in Spartan 3e starter board. It's my first time doing project in VHDL.

And I get some warnings:

```
WARNING:Xst:2677 - Node <cur_val1_0> of sequential type is unconnected in block <top>.
WARNING:Xst:2677 - Node <cur_val1_1> of sequential type is unconnected in block <top>.
WARNING:Xst:2677 - Node <cur_val1_2> of sequential type is unconnected in block <top>.
WARNING:Xst:2677 - Node <cur_val1_3> of sequential type is unconnected in block <top>.
WARNING:Xst:2677 - Node <next_val1_0> of sequential type is unconnected in block <top>.
WARNING:Xst:2677 - Node <next_val1_1> of sequential type is unconnected in block <top>.
WARNING:Xst:2677 - Node <next_val1_2> of sequential type is unconnected in block <top>.
WARNING:Xst:2677 - Node <next_val1_3> of sequential type is unconnected in block <top>.
```

```
WARNING:Xst:737 - Found 4-bit latch for signal <next_val2>. Latches may be generated from incomplete case or if statements. We do not recommend the use of latches in FPGA/CPLD designs, as they may lead to timing problems.
WARNING:Xst:737 - Found 4-bit latch for signal <next_val3>. Latches may be generated from incomplete case or if statements. We do not recommend the use of latches in FPGA/CPLD designs, as they may lead to timing problems.
WARNING:Xst:737 - Found 4-bit latch for signal <next_val4>. Latches may be generated from incomplete case or if statements. We do not recommend the use of latches in FPGA/CPLD designs, as they may lead to timing problems.
WARNING:Xst:737 - Found 4-bit latch for signal <next_state>. Latches may be generated from incomplete case or if statements. We do not recommend the use of latches in FPGA/CPLD designs, as they may lead to timing problems.
```

And here's my source code:

```
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
USE IEEE.std_logic_arith.all;
USE IEEE.std_logic_signed.all;
USE IEEE.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity top is
    Port (  
        PB1:in STD_LOGIC;
        PB2:in STD_LOGIC;
        PB3:in STD_LOGIC;
        PB4:in STD_LOGIC;
        clock:in STD_LOGIC;
        unlock1: out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
        unlock2: out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
        unlock3: out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
        unlock4: out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
        LED1:out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0); --LED 0 - 3
        LED2:out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0) --LED 4 - 7
);
end top;

architecture Behavioral of top is
subtype val_type is integer range 0 to 9;
signal cur_val1, cur_val2, cur_val3, cur_val4 : val_type;
signal reset_state, save_state : val_type;
signal next_val1, next_val2, next_val3, next_val4 : val_type;
signal save_type1, save_type2, save_type3, save_type4: val_type;
signal unlock_type1, unlock_type2, unlock_type3, unlock_type4: val_type;

type state_type is (s0,s1,s2,s3);
signal cur_state, next_state : state_type;

begin

VAL_PROC: process (clock)
begin
    if rising_edge(clock) then
        cur_val1 <= next_val1;
        cur_val2 <= next_val2;
        cur_val3 <= next_val3;
        cur_val4 <= next_val4;
    end if;
end process;

STATE_PROC: process(clock,PB4)
begin
    if(PB4='1') then    
        cur_state <= s0;   
    elsif rising_edge(clock) then    
        cur_state <= next_state;   
    end if;
end process;

NEXT_STATE_PROC: process(cur_state, cur_val1,cur_val2,cur_val3,cur_val4, PB2, PB3, PB4)
begin
case cur_state is
    when s0 =>
        if(PB4='1') then
            next_state <= s0;
        elsif(PB2='1') then
            next_state <= s1;
        end if;
        case cur_val1 is
            when 0 =>     
                if(PB3='1') then      
                    next_val1 <= 1;
                end if;
            when 1 =>     
                if(PB3='1') then      
                    next_val1 <= 2;
                end if;
            when 2 to 8 =>
                if(PB3='1') then      
                    next_val1 <= cur_val1 + 1;
                end if;
            when 9 =>
                if(PB3='1') then      
                    next_val1 <= 0;
                end if;
        end case;

    when s1 =>     
        if(PB4='1') then
            next_state <= s0;
        elsif(PB2='1') then
            next_state <= s1;
        end if;
        case cur_val2 is
            when 0 =>     
                if(PB3='1') then      
                    next_val2 <= 1;
                end if;
            when 1 =>     
                if(PB3='1') then      
                    next_val2 <= 2;
                end if;
            when 2 to 8 =>
                if(PB3='1') then      
                    next_val2 <= cur_val1 + 1;
                end if;
            when 9 =>
                if(PB3='1') then      
                    next_val2 <= 0;
                end if;
        end case;

    when s2 =>
        if(PB4='1') then
            next_state <= s0;
        elsif(PB2='1') then
            next_state <= s1;
        end if;
        case cur_val3 is
            when 0 =>     
                if(PB3='1') then      
                    next_val3 <= 1;
                end if;
            when 1 =>     
                if(PB3='1') then      
                    next_val3 <= 2;
                end if;
            when 2 to 8 =>
                if(PB3='1') then      
                    next_val3 <= cur_val1 + 1;
                end if;
            when 9 =>
                if(PB3='1') then      
                    next_val3 <= 0;
                end if;
        end case;

    when s3 =>
        if(PB4='1') then
            next_state <= s0;
        elsif(PB2='1') then
            next_state <= s1;
        end if;
        case cur_val4 is
            when 0 =>     
                if(PB3='1') then      
                    next_val4 <= 1;
                end if;
            when 1 =>     
                if(PB3='1') then      
                    next_val4 <= 2;
                end if;
            when 2 to 8 =>
                if(PB3='1') then      
                    next_val4 <= cur_val1 + 1;
                end if;
            when 9 =>
                if(PB3='1') then      
                    next_val4 <= 0;
                end if;
        end case;

    end case;
end process;

OUTPUT_VALUE_PROC:process(cur_val1, cur_val2, cur_val3, cur_val4)
begin
    case cur_val1 is    
        when 0 => LED1 <= "0000";    
        when 1 => LED1 <= "0001";    
        when 2 => LED1 <= "0010";    
        when 3 => LED1 <= "0011";    
        when 4 => LED1 <= "0100";    
        when 5 => LED1 <= "0101";    
        when 6 => LED1 <= "0110";    
        when 7 => LED1 <= "0111";    
        when 8 => LED1 <= "1000";    
        when 9 => LED1 <= "1001";
    end case;
    case cur_val2 is    
        when 0 => LED1 <= "0000";    
        when 1 => LED1 <= "0001";    
        when 2 => LED1 <= "0010";    
        when 3 => LED1 <= "0011";    
        when 4 => LED1 <= "0100";    
        when 5 => LED1 <= "0101";    
        when 6 => LED1 <= "0110";    
        when 7 => LED1 <= "0111";    
        when 8 => LED1 <= "1000";    
        when 9 => LED1 <= "1001";
    end case;
    case cur_val3 is    
        when 0 => LED1 <= "0000";    
        when 1 => LED1 <= "0001";    
        when 2 => LED1 <= "0010";    
        when 3 => LED1 <= "0011";    
        when 4 => LED1 <= "0100";    
        when 5 => LED1 <= "0101";    
        when 6 => LED1 <= "0110";    
        when 7 => LED1 <= "0111";    
        when 8 => LED1 <= "1000";    
        when 9 => LED1 <= "1001";
    end case;
    case cur_val4 is    
        when 0 => LED1 <= "0000";    
        when 1 => LED1 <= "0001";    
        when 2 => LED1 <= "0010";    
        when 3 => LED1 <= "0011";    
        when 4 => LED1 <= "0100";    
        when 5 => LED1 <= "0101";    
        when 6 => LED1 <= "0110";    
        when 7 => LED1 <= "0111";    
        when 8 => LED1 <= "1000";    
        when 9 => LED1 <= "1001";
    end case;
end process;

--SAVEANDRESET_PROC: process (save_type1, save_type2, save_type3, save_type4,PB4, PB1)
--begin
--  if (PB1= '1') then
--      save_type1 <= cur_val1;
--      save_type2 <= cur_val2;
--      save_type3 <= cur_val3;
--      save_type4 <= cur_val4;
--  elsif (PB4='1') then
--      save_type1 <= 0;
--      save_type2 <= 0;
--      save_type3 <= 0;
--      save_type4 <= 0;
--      if (PB1= '1') then
--      save_type1 <= cur_val1;
--      save_type2 <= cur_val2;
--      save_type3 <= cur_val3;
--      save_type4 <= cur_val4;
--      end if;
--  end if;
--end process;

--UNLOCK_PROC: process (save_type1, cur_val1, save_type2, cur_val2, save_type3, cur_val3, save_type4, cur_val4)
--begin
--  if(cur_val1 = save_type1 and 
--  cur_val2 = save_type2 and 
--  cur_val3 = save_type3 and 
--  cur_val4 = save_type4 ) then
--      LED2<="1111";
--      LED1<="0000";
--  else
--      LED2<="0000";
--      LED1<="1111";
--  end if;

--  case unlock_type1 is
--      when 0 to 1 => unlock1 <= "1111";
--      when 2 to 9 => unlock1 <= "1111";
--  end case;
--  case unlock_type2 is
--      when 0 to 1 => unlock2 <= "1111";
--      when 2 to 9 => unlock2 <= "1111";
--  end case;
--  case unlock_type3 is
--      when 0 to 1 => unlock3 <= "1111";
--      when 2 to 9 => unlock3 <= "1111";
--  end case;
--  case unlock_type4 is
--      when 0 to 1 => unlock4 <= "1111";
--      when 2 to 9 => unlock4 <= "1111";
--  end case;
--  
--end process;

OUTPUT_PROC:process(cur_state)
begin
    case cur_state is    
        when s0 => LED2 <= "0001";    
        when s1 => LED2 <= "0011";    
        when s2 => LED2 <= "0111";    
        when s3 => LED2 <= "1111";      
    end case;
end process;

end behavioral;
```

I have spend 4 weeks in this, this is some basic of my project, because I have to restart by going piece by piece to facilitate troubleshooting of why's my LED1 and LED2 did'nt synchronize with the Push Button (PB) also I'm still trying to figure it out how to make it simple as possible, because that code I think is still too long and isn't quite efficient. This warn and some trouble I have known happen after I simulate in iSim, then found out that there's a mistake in my code but I can't figure it out and I am now clueless. :(

Thank you for your time.

Comment: See the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) => Asking , [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). There doesn't appear to be an actual question here. The guidelines are intended to maximize the chances of providing value in your question and it's answers as a search resource for future readers.

Comment: IEEE Std 1976.6-2004 (RTL Synthesis, withdrawn) 6.2.1.1 Level-sensitive storage from prcess with sensitivity list "A level-sensitive storage element shall be modeled for a signal (or variable) when all the following apply: a) The signal (or variable) has an explicit assignment. b) The signal (or variable) does not have an execution path with <clock_edge> as a condition. c) There are executions of the process that do not execute an explicit assignment (via an assignment statement) to the signal (or variable)." We call those latches.

Comment: oh okay then thanks a lot @user1155120 for the information and advance.

Answer (score 0):

In your state process you need to state that the next_val signals will hold on to their previous value. This is because you are only changing one of them in each of your states in your state machine. This is producing the latch warnings above.

```
NEXT_STATE_PROC: process(cur_state, cur_val1,cur_val2,cur_val3,cur_val4, PB2, PB3, PB4)
begin
next_val1 <= cur_val1;
next_val2 <= cur_val2;
next_val3 <= cur_val3;
next_val4 <= cur_val4;
case cur_state is
```

Also, you seem to not be using cur_val2,3 and 4 as you are adding cur_val1 to in lines where your case statements' cur_val  vlaues matches the condition

```
            when 2 to 8 =>
                if(PB3='1') then      
                    next_val4 <= cur_val1 + 1;
```

Should this be :

```
            when 2 to 8 =>
                if(PB3='1') then      
                    next_val4 <= cur_val4 + 1;
```

Try these fixes and see what happens.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

you r treating signals as if they r variable! it's not working that way.
signals are real wires in fpga but variables are like values. in the process u should use variable and at the end assign them to the corresponding signals. 
good luck